# linux scheduler on multicore

Tags: linux-kernel

as linux kernel is preemptive:

1. on which core does the scheduler run?
2. how does it schedule on another core (context switch) - if the kernel space is running on the other core?
3. how does it schedule on another core (context switch) - if the user space is running on the other core?
4. if kernel can run on all cores - is it like distributed algorithm (every kernel thread is independent on other kernel modules - and there are locks on kernel data structures) - or there is a one main entity to orchestrate all kernel threads?
5. so in order to schedule - the scheduler change the waiting list in each core (is this a centralized data struct?) and every piece of kernel on every core look in this data struck and pick the next process to run on the same core?
6. when scheduler interrupt occurs - which scheduler process is running? or there is scheduler process on each core with interrupt on each core - and every scheduler process on each core - either schedule from its run queue or use migration thread to move a process to other run queue?

Answer (score 2):

> on which core does the scheduler run?

on all cores

> how does it schedule on another core (context switch) - if the kernel space is running on the other core?

That's the thing – a context switch is something that happens locally on the core. So, there's no "running on the other core".

Not quite sure you've really got the correct meaning of "context switch". I think you might mean "re-scheduling a task on a different core".

Also, hint: don't think of things as "is running"; that's not how computers actually work, before things get nice and abstracted by exactly the mechanism you're trying to understand.

Think of: "What piece of code is this CPU core executing, right now?", and you'll realize that basically all these things are *actively* done by the code executed, or by some hardware interrupt.

> how does it schedule on another core (context switch) - if the user space is running on the other core?

Well, if a process is not running, it's on a wait list, and that wait list is queried as soon as the kernel code running on processor core decides it's an idle time (e.g. through having handled as much as possible of a system call) by code running on that core itself (that's kind of logical). The way the decision "oh, this waiting process is what I'm going to jump into" is done does involve *locality* (i.e. are we the same core that was executing it the last time?), but not exclusively.

> is it like distributed algorithm (every kernel thread is independent on other kernel modules - and there are locks on kernel data structures) - or there is a one main entity to orchestrate all kernel threads?

Mostly the first.

Answer (score 1):

What you call the *scheduler* is in fact a collection of kernel routines that can be executed following specific events, interrupts or even calls from userland processes.

The most basic data used by the scheduler is the runqueue.
Under CFS, every processor has it's own runqueue of tasks, and no task occurs at the same time in more than one runqueue.

As a conclusion of this, yes, we could say that CFS runs on all processors.
And for the 5th question, no it is not a centralized data structure.

Rem. Id to Marcus Müller's answer regarding some misunderstanding of *context-switch*.
I will then assume your question being about thread *migration* :
Migration of thread from one core to another is managed by the [[migration/x] kernel threads](https://www.halolinux.us/kernel-architecture/the-migration-thread.html) (one per core)

About locks : Yes, kernel threads sometimes lock (using Spinlocks and Mutexes) but of course [the fewer the better](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/kernel-hacking/locking.html).